# which one is correct? such a argument or such an argument?

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct?
"such a argument" vs "such an argument"

ex)
such a(an) argument should be applied to ~~.

Edit:
The reason why i was confused about it was that "such a" might be some sort of preposition like "such as" or it is wrong but fixed expression like
"pitch in".
And i can find many usages of "such a" from the internet, such as

```
"Why is the French Election causing such a argument between American liberals vs conservatives."
```

Comment: please add the research that you have done.   Why do you think English sometimes uses "an" instead of "a".  What have you been told about the rules for this? Why are you having difficulty applying those rules here?

Comment: In general grammar, an is more correct, right? But why i can get search results of "such a argument" from google search? and also get result of "such an argument" simultaneously?

Comment: Why do you think English sometimes uses "an" instead of "a". What have you been told about the rules for this? Why are you having difficulty applying those rules here?

Comment: 'an' starts before in front of 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' type noun.

Comment: Is "argument"  an 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' type noun?

Comment: so, such an argument is more correct?

Comment: You keep asking questions. Please also answer mine:  What letter sound does "argument" begin with.  If you think it begins with an "a" sound then you know the answer to your question, and you should "Post your answer" in the box below.  But you should also think about these (correct) examples "An hour"  and "An old box" and "A uniform".

Comment: What do you mean "Post your answer"? You mean you want me to answer my question? And close thread?

Comment: Yes, and  no.  I want you to answer your question, and leave this thread open.

Comment: But you can accept your answer (if you think it is the best) accepting an answer isn't the same as closing a thread.

Comment: Anyway thank you for your answer...

Comment: For a more complete answer, see this question on ELU: [When should I use "a" vs "an"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/)

Comment: Can you edit your question and tell us why you were confused.  You would probably get good helpful answers about the grammar rule. The question would also be more interesting. Not a bad thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like James'comment

```
Such an argument
```

This is correct one.

This is because

```
‘an’ should be followed by a vowel (a,e,i,o,u) and a should be followed by a consonant:
an elephant
a car
```

ref : https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/when-use-a

Comment: *Why* is "an" the right word? Make your answer useful for other users who may see your question  in the future.

Comment: What a strange source. The h in 'hour' isn't "weakly pronounced," it's silent.